# Can I use a Lightweight Migration to move a Relationship in a Hierarchy?

Tags: core-data

I have a Core Data model that includes Document Entities and Quote Entities. There is a many-Quotes-to-one-Document Relationship in the model.

I am introducing a new type of Quote, so I would like to create a parent BaseQuote Entity, that will have TextQuote and ImageQuote 'child' Entities. The existing Quote will become a TextQuote.

So, I need to push the Quote side of the Relationship down the hierarchy into BaseQuote.

The [lightweight migration documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration) says that I can manage "changes to hierarchies" and "changes to relationships", but is not clear that it handles both at once!

If I check the mapping, Core Data *thinks* it is possible, `inferredMappingModel` does not throw an error:

```
NSMappingModel.inferredMappingModel(forSourceModel: lastVersion, destinationModel: thisVersion)
```

However, when I run the migration I get a crash with the message:

```
Validation error missing attribute values on mandatory destination relationship
```

It turns out the relationship is not being correctly populated by the migration - although structurally it seems to have worked.

Has anyone tried this before and got it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is beyond lightweight migration. The page you link to explains that relationship changes include adding, deleting, renaming, and changing to-one to to-many or back. What you need is to move the relationship from one entity to a different one in the hierarchy, that is, take a relationship to `Quote` and move it to the new `BaseQuote`. It would probably be fine if you were changing the hierarchy and making one of those changes (renaming the relationship, for example). Lightweight migration doesn't cover re-targeting a relationship to a different part of the hierarchy, though.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I think you're right. I will see if it can be done over a few model iterations.

Comment: I thought I might be able to do this in a couple of lightweight steps within William Boles' progressive migration pattern, but I couldn't get it all the way without a mapping model. https://williamboles.me/progressive-core-data-migration/